# Controlling amend permissions on TFS Power Tools “Team Members”

Tags: permissions

After installing TFS Power Tools, you get an additional node “Team Members” in the “Team Explorer”, which brings with it some very handy functionality. Here you can arrange all your users into teams, providing you with a nice overview.

The problem is that when everyone amends these, it becomes a nightmare to maintain and guarantee the correctness of the teams and members of teams.

Is it possible to control the access / permissions here, by specifying who may edit the teams?

I am using TFS2010 with Visual Studion 2010 on Win7.

Kind regards,
Morné

Answer (score 0):

No, but in TFS 2012 Team's become a first-class citizen.

These can be fully secured and controlled.

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh500417.aspx).